# Test class for sobject record type

Tags: apex

I am trying to cover the below class. I am getting 71%. Can you please let me know how to cover .

```
public class OpportunityRecordTypeSelectionCtr {

@AuraEnabled
public static string findRecordTypes(string objName){
    string returnString='';
    string queryString='Select id, name from RecordType where sobjectType =: objName and IsActive=true ORDER BY Name DESC';
    List<sobject> recordList= Database.query(queryString);
    List<RecordTypeWrapper> wrapperList=new List<RecordTypeWrapper>();
    for(sobject sb : recordList)  {
        RecordTypeWrapper rw=new RecordTypeWrapper();
        rw.recordTypeLabel=string.valueof(sb.get('name'));
        rw.recordTypeId=string.valueof(sb.get('id'));
        wrapperList.add(rw);
    } 
    returnString= JSON.serialize(wrapperList);
    system.debug('*****'+returnString);
    return returnString;
}
public class RecordTypeWrapper{
    public string recordTypeLabel{get;set;}
    public string recordTypeId{get;set;}
}
```

}

Test class:

```
@isTest
private class OpportunityRecordTypeSelectionCtr_Test {
    static testMethod void testRecordTypes(){
    string objName;
    OpportunityRecordTypeSelectionCtr.findRecordTypes(objName);
      string recordTypeLabel;
        string recordTypeId;
    OpportunityRecordTypeSelectionCtr.RecordTypeWrapper recordTypeWrap = new OpportunityRecordTypeSelectionCtr.RecordTypeWrapper();
     recordTypeWrap.recordTypeLabel = recordTypeLabel;
        recordTypeWrap.recordTypeId = recordTypeId;
    }
}
```

Unable to cover below lines of code.

```
RecordTypeWrapper rw=new RecordTypeWrapper();
            rw.recordTypeLabel=string.valueof(sb.get('name'));
            rw.recordTypeId=string.valueof(sb.get('id'));
            wrapperList.add(rw);
```

Comment: Please do not destroy the contents of your question. Doing so invalidates answers and removes value for the community. I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test class is invoking your code with a `null` sObject name value.

```
string objName;
OpportunityRecordTypeSelectionCtr.findRecordTypes(objName);
```

`objName` is uninitialized and `null`. Your query therefore returns an empty list.

```
string queryString='Select id, name from RecordType where sobjectType =: objName and IsActive=true ORDER BY Name DESC';
```

and `recordList` is therefore empty, and the `for` loop never executes.

```
for(sobject sb : recordList)  {
```

Test with the name of an object that has record types in your org.

Comment: I am using sobject as Opportunity and it has two record types 1. Standard Opportunity 2. Opportunity Grouping. Can u please let me know how to refer these objects in test class

Comment: You need to set `objName` equal to `'Opportunity'`.